# ftp_rawlist returns false on ProFTPd server

Tags: php, ftp

1. I have a ProFTPd on a linux server (ProFTPd version 1.33 on Debian Linux 6.0.7 Linux 2.6.32-042stab078.27 on x86_64) that lets access to some users to their home directories.
2. I also have another FTP server on a Mac OS X Server.

If I use solution (2), I'm able to perform `ftp_rawlist` to have a raw list of all directories and files.

If I use solution (1), `ftp_rawlist` ALWAYS returns `FALSE`, even if the directory is not empty.

Users have permission to do anything they want inside their home directories on both servers (get directory listing, create and delete files, etc...). NO limits at all.

I really can't uderstand why I always get `false` on ProFTPd.

I gave a look around internet and discovered that there were some bugs on that function, but on previous versions of PHP. I'm running PHP version 5.3.3-7+squeeze16 and there are no bugs reported for this version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `passive mode`

```
ftp_pasv($conn, true);
```

Usually you need passive mode if your `FTP` server is behind `firewall`, what is passive mode you can read here - [What is the difference between active and passive FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp)

Comment: Usually you need `passive mode` if your `FTP` server is behind firewall, what is passive mode you can read here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp