# Twisted FTPClient with Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, twisted

I'm trying to run a simple FTPServer on EC2. My client connects to it fine, and I can make and remove directories. However, I get the following error whenever I try to store or retrieve a file: **Failure: twisted.protocols.ftp.CommandFailed: ["425 Can't open data connection."]**

I've tested the server on my localhost, and everything behaves as normal. I was paranoid and decided to turn on all ports in my security groups, but it still doesn't work. Am I missing something when setting up my EC2 machine?

Answer (score 1):

Your FTP client appears to be in active mode, and is (like most client computers these days) behind a NAT or firewall which does not permit inbound connections.

[There's another question on Stack Overflow about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp/1699163#1699163) that quite clearly explains the differences between active and passive mode in FTP; you should read it.

Configure your client to use passive mode, or "PASV", and it ought to work.

Comment: I actually tried changing the FTPClient to use passive mode, but it gives me 550: Internal Server Error. I'm using a VirtualBox image for my client, and I'm wondering if there are some settings I need to change on the client side to disable the firewalls.