# PhpStorm 9: Why doesn't the remote path's directories/files display when connected via FTP

Tags: ftp, permissions, settings, phpstorm, profile

I am trying to connect to a remote host in PhpStorm 9 via FTP and it connects to the host but does not display any files/directories.

I am able to ftp and see files/directories just fine via FileZilla with the same ftp profile/settings I used in PhpStorm 9.

Why am I not able to see files/directories via FTP in PhpStorm 9?

Comment: **1)** Double check the login details/IPs **2)** Make sure that you are seeing correct folder **3)** Make sure that you are using correct connection (in case if you have more than one set up) **4)** Try switching between Active and Passive FTP modes.

Comment: u sir are a genius, it was the passive mode option that needed to be checked.  What is passive mode btw?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try switching between Active ans Passive FTP modes (option is located in [Advanced Options dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/advanced-options-dialog.html?search=ftp) of the [Deployment](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/deployment.html) settings/preferences page.

[image]

Comment: Additionally I had to switch from FTPS to FTP to show me the list of directories (even if it could also connect via FTPS successfully).