# Download a ftp file through socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, ftp

I'm trying to download a file from FTP server through socket in C. The client is already logged in. Control socket is OK. Data socket is OK. But it still can't download file(with RETR Command). I get the following error message from FTP server:

> Server reply : 421 Local resource failure: open data port failed.

I don't understand this message. Does anyone have any idea?

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

  //Initial setting
  int CONTROL_CONNECTION_PORT = 21;
  int DATA_CONNECTION_PORT = 20;
  strcpy(MY_HOST_IP,"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
  strcpy(MY_DATA_PORT, ",34,184");//8888
  strcpy(FTP_IP, argv[1]);
  strcpy(FTP_ID, "ooxx");
  strcpy(FTP_PWD, "xxoo");
  strcpy(FILE_NAME, argv[2]);


  sprintf(Buff, "WSASTARTUP = %d", ReturnValue);
  output(Buff);

  // Connect to the server(CONTROL SOCKET)
  SOCKET ControlSocket = ConnectFTP(FTP_IP, CONTROL_CONNECTION_PORT);//CONNECT IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  PORT: 21 == 0
  // Server reply: FTP server ready.
  receiving(ControlSocket);


  // Send our username to the ftp-server.
  sprintf(Buff,"USER %s",FTP_ID);
  sending(ControlSocket, Buff);
  // Server reply : 331 Password required for User ooxx.
  receiving(ControlSocket);


  // Send our password to the ftp-server.
  sprintf(Buff,"PASS %s",FTP_PWD);
  sending(ControlSocket, Buff);
  // Server reply : 230 User ooxx logged in.
  receiving(ControlSocket);


  // In Active mode (DATA PROT SETTING)
  sprintf(Buff, "PORT %s%s",MY_HOST_IP,MY_DATA_PORT);
  sending(ControlSocket, Buff);
  // Server reply : 200 PORT command successful.
  receiving(ControlSocket);


  // Connect to the server(DATA SOCKET)
  SOCKET DataSocket = ConnectFTP(FTP_IP, DATA_CONNECTION_PORT);//CONNECT IP:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  PORT: 20 == 0


  // Get a file from server
  sprintf(Buff,"RETR %s", FILE_NAME);
  sending(ControlSocket, Buff);
  // Server reply : 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for FileA.
  receiving(ControlSocket);
  // "Server reply : 421 Local resource failure: open data port failed."
  receiving(ControlSocket);



  // ---RECEIVING FILE FROM THE DATA SOCKET---
  receiving(DataSocket);//?????

  // Server reply.
  receiving(ControlSocket);//??????


  //closed socket
  closesocket(ControlSocket);
  closesocket(DataSocket);

  WSACleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW,the file on the FTP server is TEXT file.

Comment: This looks like C code. Why did you add tag for another language (C++)?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use an active FTP as a passive FTP. http://www.slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: SORRY I trying to remove C++ tag

Comment: @slacksite.com/other/ftp.html – Let_Me_Be

I have read the RFC959,  I'm trying to write a program with Active mode.

Comment: @Ellison Well, this isn't how active FTP works. In active FTP the server connects to you. What you are doing is passive mode.

Comment: Hmmmm...Could you please tell me which part is wrong then I can fix this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Thank you !! I know the theory, but I'm not good on implementation, 
so i don't need to use the functions likes "bind", "listen" , "accept" right?

Comment: How are you planning to write a socket-based program if you do not use those functions?

Comment: Because I found many client-side program(In active mode) example didn't use these functions, so i asked this question.

Comment: @user1766169
Thank you for edited my post!!!
It's looks better now : )

Comment: In Active mode, you have to open a listening socket using `bind()` and `listen()`, then send a `PORT` or `EPRT` command telling the FTP server the IP/Port where it needs to connect to reach that socket, and then use `accept()` to receive that connection. In Passive mode, you send a `PASV` or `EPSV` command to ask the server to open a listening socket and the FTP server replies telling you the IP/Port where you need to `connect()` to reach that socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your help!!! It's really a great help to me!!!!!