# NppFtp Passive Mode not working

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I have the Notepad++ FTP plugin installed, and I'd like to use it in Passive Mode - I don't want my files saved to the server immediately; I want to be able to control when I upload a file.

However, switching between Active and Passive mode in the profile manager appears to not do anything. Whenever I open a file from the local cache, modify it, and save it it gets uploaded immediately.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this feature just broken?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the plugin, but doesn't that simply configure the FTP client to use passive FTP instead of active FTP, which is a setting controlling how the client connects to the server? Is it documented somewhere that this "passive" mode does what you expect? I also doubt there's just one FTP plugin for Notepad++, so naming the one you use explicitly might help.

Comment: When I looked up how to to turn off the automatic sync in NppFtp, the answer I found was to switch to Passive mode: https://sites.google.com/site/an324wiki/home/nppftp

As to there being multiple plugins, yes, but there is only one referred to as NppFtp :)

Comment: The person who wrote that is wrong. The setting displayed _is_ about the [passive and active connection mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp). I don't know whether this plugin supports what you're looking for. Also, you may want to look into application lifecycle management: you seem to be lacking version control and [DTAP environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production); working on files and pushing them directly to the server is considered a bad practice.

Comment: Hmm... seems like you might be right. I'm looking through the source code on github and there is no check for that variable at the place where the local cache is uploaded after the save event.

And thanks for the advice, haha, I know that version control and DTAP are pretty much required - this is just a few very simple files that I'm editing as part of a proof-of-concept :)