# What is the difference between HTTP vs FTP?

Tags: http, ftp

I'm just learning about it and I have these things in mind but I'm not quite sure about them. Is there any wrong ideas about my findings? Please elaborate it in simple terms.

1. HTTP:

   - used to view websites between web servers
   - web server files to another web server
   - used to transfer small files (in text form)
   - used to have access in WWW
2. FTP

   - used to access and transfer files between a local machine and a web server
   - local files to a web server
   - used to transfer large files (in any form)
   - used to have access in a remote server

Comment: FTP is an older protocol used to transfer files over a network. HTTP can do more that file transfers. Take a look here for details: https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/ftp-vs-http.html

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is limited to questions *specific to software development*. General computing questions are a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) (note there is a section on the wikipedia page illustrates the differences between HTTP and FTP) are both [application layer protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer).

See also [here](http://cdn.differencebetween.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/ftp_http.jpg).

HTTP:

- used to make request response communications between a server and a client
- this communication can be used to both upload and download text and binary information
- state less
- faster when transferring many small files
- used for web pages with or without authentication required

FTP:

- also performs uploading and downloading of information
- stateful control connection
- faster for single large file transfers
- file transfer authentication needed
- limited support of pipe-lining

The big difference is that HTTP fixes many of the issues incurred by FTP. One example is that FTP has very little overhead and no metadata while HTTP provides this and there HTTP supports the sending of multiple files. Also HTTP is state less.

Some extra sources I would advise you read for more information on this are:
1. http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-ftp-and-http/
2.
https://daniel.haxx.se/docs/ftp-vs-http.html

Also for more information on the different types of FTP, I would advise looking at this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp).