# FTP upload file failed in Docker container

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ftp-server

I have a spring boot app using library apache commons-net
I have a FTP server running on AWS EC2.
Filezilla connect and upload file normally.
Local app connect and upload file normally.
When i run this app using Docker, the app connect to ftp succeed,but it cannot upload file.
Reply code is: 500
**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM openjdk:11
RUN mkdir /app
COPY build/libs/aws-batch1-1.0.0.jar /app/aws-batch1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/aws-batch1.jar","Test"]
```

**Image build command**:

```
docker build -t aws-batch1 .
```

**Image run command**:

```
docker run aws-batch1
```

**Code connect FTP**:

```java
private boolean connectFTPServer() throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("CONNECT");
        boolean flg = true;
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(FTP_SERVER_ADDRESS, FTP_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER);
            ftpClient.login(FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("CONNECT FAILED", e);
            flg = false;
        }

        int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        LOGGER.info("replyCode: " + replyCode);
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
            flg = false;
        }
        if (!flg) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        return flg;
    }
```

**Code upload file**:

```java
public boolean uploadFile(byte[] content, String fileName)
            throws IOException {
        boolean flg = false;
        LOGGER.info("uploadFile");
        if (connectFTPServer()) {
            LOGGER.info("connectFTPServer success");
            LOGGER.info("content: " + new String(content));
            try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content)) {
                ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                boolean storeFile = ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, is);
                LOGGER.info("storeFile: " + storeFile);
                LOGGER.info("ftpClient.getReplyCode(): " + ftpClient.getReplyCode());

                flg = storeFile &&
                        ftpClient.getReplyCode() ==
                                FTPReply.CLOSING_DATA_CONNECTION;
                if (!flg) {
                    throw new IOException("FTP error");
                }
            } finally {
                closeConnectionFTPClient();
            }
        }
        return flg;
    }
```

**Log when upload on local successful**:

```
uploadFile
CONNECT
replyCode: 230
connectFTPServer success
content: test
storeFile: true
ftpClient.getReplyCode(): 226
```

**Log when upload on Docker failed**:

```
uploadFile
CONNECT
replyCode: 230
connectFTPServer success
content: test
storeFile: false
ftpClient.getReplyCode(): 500
```

Please help me. Am I missing any steps?

**UPDATE**:Thanks @Metin
I have updated the code to connect to ftp client as below:

```java
private boolean connectFTPServer() throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info("CONNECT");
        boolean flg = true;
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(FTP_SERVER_ADDRESS, FTP_SERVER_PORT_NUMBER);
            ftpClient.login(FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("CONNECT FAILED", e);
            flg = false;
        }

        int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        LOGGER.info("replyCode: " + replyCode);
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
            flg = false;
        }
        if (!flg) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        return flg;
    }
```

and it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to read about the differences of active and passive mode ftp: [What is the difference between active and passive FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp)

You should come to the conclusion that active mode ftp is not suited for containerized ftp clients, due to the nature that the server activily tries to initate a data connection to the ftp client, which is not possible for a container (unless the container uses network: host, which is typicaly unwanted).

With passive mode ftp on the other hand, the server will tell your ftp client which port needs to be used for the next data connection.